# Loop not taking empty User Input Field into account

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file

I have a Batch File which contains a HTML form which users have 3 input fields for 1.Customer ID 
    2.First Name 
    3.Last Name

If i leave the First Field/Customer ID empty then it carries the Second Field/First Names value into the First Fields slot.

This then makes the Customer ID variable value = to the Fist Name variable value which then cause my program to fail.

```bat
<!-- :
:: textSubmitter.bat
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~f0"') do (
    set "CustomerID=%%a"
    set "FirstName=%%b"
    set "LastName=%%c"
)

echo Your Customer ID is %CustomerID%
echo Your First Name is %FirstName%
echo Your Last Name is %LastName%
pause

IF "%CustomerID%"=="" (
    @echo
    echo.>"C:\Users\C28\Documents\RoboticProcessAutomation(RPA)\TestingStuff\%FirstName%%LastName%.csv"
    sqlcmd -S IX.COM -d GlblTransprncy -E -Q " EXEC dbo.GetSimilarCustIDs18 '%CustomerID%', '%FirstName%', '%LastName%' " -s "," -o "C:\Users\C283050\Documents\RoboticProcessAutomation(RPA)\TestingStuff\%FirstName%%LastName%.csv"
    pause
)  ELSE (
    @echo
    echo.>"C:\Users\C28\Documents\RoboticProcessAutomation(RPA)\TestingStuff\%CustomerID%.csv"
    echo Results for Customer ID will be returned shortly, Please check folder for the entered Customer ID results
    sqlcmd -S IX.COM -d GlblTransprncy -E -Q " EXEC dbo.GetSimilarCustIDs18 '%CustomerID%', '%@FirstName%', '%LastName%' " -s "," -o "C:\Users\C283050\Documents\RoboticProcessAutomation(RPA)\TestingStuff\%CustomerID%.csv"
)
goto :EOF

-->

<html>
    <head>
        <title>COI Request</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script language='javascript' >
            function pipeText() {
                var CustomerID=document.getElementById('CustomerID').value;
                var FirstName=document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
                var LastName=document.getElementById('LastName').value;

                var Batch = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
                close(Batch.WriteLine(CustomerID+','+FirstName+','+LastName));
            }
        </script>

        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center"> 
            <label for="Student">CustomerID:</label>
            <input type='text' name='CustomerID' size='25'></input><br>
        </div>

        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center"> 
            <label for="Student">First Name:</label>
            <input type='text' name='FirstName' size='25'></input><br>
        </div>

        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center"> 
            <label for="Student">Last Name:</label>
            <input type='text' name='LastName' size='25'></input><br>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <button onclick='pipeText()'>Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

If the Customer ID/First input field is left empty then the loop should leave this variable value for Customer ID as being empty rather than taking the next value in line i.e. the First Name value

Comment: Your `For` loop is defining its value as the string up until the first returned comma of the output, however leading delimiters are ignored, so if nothing is entered the first comma is ignored setting `FirstName` as `%%a`. `%CustomerID%` will only not have a value, if none of the inputs were entered. I would suggest that you change your javascript code to `close(Batch.WriteLine('"'+CustomerID+'","'+FirstName+'","'+LastName+'"'));` and your `Set` commands to this syntax, `Set "CustomerID=%%~a"`, `Set "FirstName=%%~b"` and `Set "LastName=%%~c"`, to preserve any empty string positions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This has put me back on the right track, it's greatly appreciated and something i wouldn't have spotted on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your For loop is defining its value as the string up until the first returned comma of the output, however leading delimiters are ignored, so if nothing is entered the first comma is ignored setting `FirstName` as `%%a`. `%CustomerID%` will only not have a value, if none of the inputs were entered.

I would suggest that you change your javascript code to:

```bat
close(Batch.WriteLine('"'+CustomerID+'","'+FirstName+'","'+LastName+'"'));
```

and your `Set` commands to this syntax to preserve any empty string positions:

```bat
Set "CustomerID=%%~a"
Set "FirstName=%%~b"
Set "LastName=%%~c"
```

Example:

```bat
<!-- ::textSubmitter.bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=1-3Delims=," %%A In ('mshta.exe "%~f0"')Do (Set "CustomerID=%%~A"
    Set "FirstName=%%~B"
    Set "LastName=%%~C")

Echo Your Customer ID is %CustomerID%
Echo Your First Name is %FirstName%
Echo Your Last Name is %LastName%
Timeout 3 /NoBreak>Nul

If "%CustomerID%"=="" (
    Do Something
)Else (
    Do something else
)
GoTo :EOF

-->

<html>
    <head>
        <title>COI Request</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script language='javascript' >
            function pipeText() {
                var CustomerID=document.getElementById('CustomerID').value;
                var FirstName=document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
                var LastName=document.getElementById('LastName').value;

                var Batch = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
                close(Batch.WriteLine('"'+CustomerID+'","'+FirstName+'","'+LastName+'"'));
            }
        </script>

        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center"> 
            <label for="Student">CustomerID:</label>
            <input type='text' name='CustomerID' size='25'></input><br>
        </div>

        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center"> 
            <label for="Student">First Name:</label>
            <input type='text' name='FirstName' size='25'></input><br>
        </div>

        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center"> 
            <label for="Student">Last Name:</label>
            <input type='text' name='LastName' size='25'></input><br>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <button onclick='pipeText()'>Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```